# OpenSSL RSA_METHOD Structure: What is the use of app_data field?

Tags: openssl, rsa

Referring to the OpenSSL RSA_METHOD structure, what is the suggested use of the **app_data** field? Documentation is very scant on this. I am also looking for any example piece of code that used this field in a meaningful way.

```
 typedef struct rsa_meth_st {    
    const char *name;    

    int (*rsa_pub_enc)(int flen, unsigned char *from,
      unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);

    int (*rsa_pub_dec)(int flen, unsigned char *from,
      unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);    

    int (*rsa_priv_enc)(int flen, unsigned char *from,
      unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);

    int (*rsa_priv_dec)(int flen, unsigned char *from,
      unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);    

    int (*rsa_mod_exp)(BIGNUM *r0, BIGNUM *I, RSA *rsa);    

    int (*bn_mod_exp)(BIGNUM *r, BIGNUM *a, const BIGNUM *p,
      const BIGNUM *m, BN_CTX *ctx, BN_MONT_CTX *m_ctx);

    int (*init)(RSA *rsa);

    int (*finish)(RSA *rsa);    

    int flags;    

    char *app_data; /* ?? */    

    int (*rsa_sign)(int type, unsigned char *m, unsigned int m_len,
       unsigned char *sigret, unsigned int *siglen, RSA *rsa);//here m points to digest of type 'type'

    int (*rsa_verify)(int type, unsigned char *m, unsigned int m_len,
       unsigned char *sigbuf, unsigned int siglen, RSA *rsa); } RSA_METHOD;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Referring to the OpenSSL RSA_METHOD structure, what is the suggested use of the app_data field?

In the case of RSA, I don't believe there's a suggested use. I believe it exists for those who need it:

```
include/openssl/rsa.h-    /* may be needed! */
include/openssl/rsa.h:    char *app_data;
```

---

I believe `app_data` in general exists for specific applications that need to carry around extra context, like an ENGINE implementation and working with key pairs. For example, this is from GOST's engine:

```
engines/ccgost/gost_crypt.c:192:    ctx->app_data = ctx->cipher_data;
```

Its also used frequently in an SSL context to provide extra state. For example:

```
...
ssl/d1_pkt.c:1390:            s->s3->in_read_app_data = 2;
ssl/s3_lib.c:3104:    s->s3->in_read_app_data = 0;
ssl/s3_lib.c:4415:    s->s3->in_read_app_data = 1;
ssl/s3_lib.c:4419:    if ((ret == -1) && (s->s3->in_read_app_data == 2)) {
ssl/s3_lib.c:4433:        s->s3->in_read_app_data = 0;
ssl/s3_pkt.c:1623:            s->s3->in_read_app_data = 2;
...
```

I believe its covered in the [`ssl(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/ssl.html) man pages; see `SSL_CTX_get_app_data`, `SSL_CTX_set_app_data`, `SSL_SESSION_get_app_data`, `SSL_SESSION_set_app_data` and friends.

---

There are at least 59 data structures that provide it:

```
openssl-1.0.2e$ grep -IR app_data * | egrep "(char*|void*)" | wc -l
      59
```

---

> Documentation is very scant on this.

Yes it is. Here are the comments I could find on it (a few `/* ?? */` were omitted):

```
crypto/evp/evp.h-    /* Application data */
crypto/evp/evp.h:    void *app_data;

crypto/evp/evp.h:    void *app_data;             /* application stuff */

demos/tunala/tunala.c-    /*
demos/tunala/tunala.c:     * We use the SSL's "app_data" to indicate a call-back induced "kill"
```